# Manually provide static / default values when mapping to OLE DB Destination from Excel Source

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I'm reading data from an `Excel Source` into an `OLE DB Destination`. For the sake of this example I'm just going to simplify the data. My `Excel Source` file has the following columns:

```
Firstname
Lastname
```

And my `OLE DB Destination` table has the following columns:

```
Firstname
Lastname
Planet
Galaxy
```

When reading the data from my `Excel Source`, `Firstname` and `Lastname` will obviously map nicely. However, how can I provide a 'default / static' value for `Planet` and `Galaxy` e.g. '`Earth`' and '`Milkyway`' ?

I can't seem to find the functionality that allows me to do that, it seems that I'm only able to do simple point-and-drag mappings in the `Data Flow`.

Answer (score 0):

Add Derived Column after your source.Expression = "Milkyway"